# How can i set prefix for all controllers in certain folder in symfony 6.3 version?

Tags: symfony, annotations, admin, prefix

In version 5.4 in annotations.yaml i set prefixes on routes, but in symfony 6.3 there is no annotations.yaml.

I tried with

```
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute
admin_controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/Admin
        namespace: App\Controller\Admin
    type: attribute
```